# Batch geocoding 1.5 million data points in SQL Server

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sql-server, geocoding

I am currently attempting to batch geocode 1.5 million points that are stored in a sql database.  The points are not very specific (ie only city, state points).  I have used ArcGIS in the past but due to the new ArcGIS online credit system, it is restrictively expensive to geocode with their database.  For that reason, I was able to access a composite geocoder that I attempted to connect to ArcGIS via the Create a geocoder feature, however, this system is not working as well (either it freezes with my database, or if I use a test dataset, it cannot match any addresses).

I am seeking suggestions on:

1. How to best setup the geocoder I have to run in ArcGIS or
2. Other methods that may work better (I am really open to anything!)

Let me know if there is more helpful information that I can provide.

Comment: So, do you still work with an online geocoder or you have obtained / created an own locator (.loc) stored on your local machine? Would you consider other options for geocoding outside of ArcGIS?

Comment: How good is the source data, formatted and clean?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to fulfill your request for "Other methods"...

I used [this post](http://dracodoc.github.io/2015/11/17/Geocoding/) to help me set up and install my own windows server to geocode US addresses.

Basic instructions are to:

1. Install PostgreSQL (open source database)
2. Install PostGIS and TIGER extensions
3. Use TIGER functions to download/install US TIGER data by state